# Parse.com не происходит загрузка данных?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, parse.com

НЕ происходит загрузка данных из сервера. Не могу понять в чем ошибка, уже блоки ставил.Включил в  info.plist  “Information Property List” add “App Transport Security Settings” and then under that add “Allow Arbitrary Loads” and set it to YES.

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class DetailSportViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageDetail: UIImageView!


    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    @IBOutlet weak var navBar: UINavigationBar!

    @IBOutlet weak var titleDetail: UILabel!


    @IBOutlet weak var prognozDetail: UILabel!

    var soccers : Soccer?
    var baskets : Basketball?
    var tenises : Tennis?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()






        textView.font = textView.font?.withSize(10)
        detailObject()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
            }


    @IBOutlet weak var outClose: UIButton! {

        didSet {
            outClose.layer.cornerRadius = 20
            outClose.layer.masksToBounds = true



        }
    }



    @IBAction func actionClose(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

    }


        func detailObject() {

           var imageData: Data? = nil

    if (imageDetail.image != nil) {
        imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageDetail.image!, 0.5)
    } else {
        print("image in imageView is nil")
        return
    }
    var file: PFFile? = nil
    if (imageData != nil) {
        file = PFFile(name: "imageDetail.jpg", data: imageData!)
    } else {
        print("image data is nil")
        return
    }
            let detailView = PFObject(className: "soccer")
            detailView["detailImageS"] = file
            detailView["detailTitles"] = "Манчестер Сити - Шахтер"
            detailView["detailTextS"] = "После потери Срны в распоряжении главного тренера «Шахтера» Пауло Фонсеки остался лишь один правый защитник – основной футболист сборной Украины Богдан Бутко."
            detailView["detailPrognozS"] = "прогноз на матч: тотал больше 10 угловых."
            detailView.saveInBackground {(success, error) -> Void in
                if(success){
                    print("Saved successful")

                } else {
                    print(error!)

                }

            }

    let query = PFQuery(className: "soccer")
            query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects:[PFObject]?, error:Error?) in


                if error == nil {
                    for objects in objects! {

                       let detailPrognozS  = objects["detailPrognozS"] as! String

                      let detailTitleS = objects["detailTitleS"] as! String
                      let detailTextS = objects["detailTextS"] as! String
                      let imageDetail = objects["detailImageS"] as? PFFile

                        self.prognozDetail.text = detailPrognozS
                        self.textView.text = detailTextS
                       self.titleDetail.text = detailTitleS
                        imageDetail?.getDataInBackground(block: { (data:Data?, error:Error?) in

                            if error == nil {
                                if let imageData = data {
                                    self.imageDetail.image = UIImage(data: imageData)

                                } else {
                                    print(error!)
                                }
                            }
                        })
                        }
                            }
                        }
                    }


}
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, а разве сервис Parse.com не закрыли?

Comment: нет, у меня все загружается.пару лет назад читал стать закрывали, уже открыли как год и работает .

Comment: не грузит в методе query.findObjectsInBackground  ?

Comment: Наверное...Это вопрос или подсказка?

Comment: ну у вас в методе куча принтов, кие выводит ? "image in imageView is nil" , "image data is nil" , "Saved successful", может ошибки какие ?

Comment: Андрей так это вы Мне подсказали так написать.Чтоб image загружалась с сервера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func detailObject() {

    query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects:[PFObject]?, error:Error?) in
        if error == nil {
            for objects in objects! {
                let detailPrognozS  = objects["detailPrognozS"] as! String
                let detailTitleS = objects["detailTitleS"] as! String
                let detailTextS = objects["detailTextS"] as! String
                let imageDetail = objects["detailImageS"] as? PFFile
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
                    self.prognozDetail.text = detailPrognozS
                    self.textView.text = detailTextS
                    self.titleDetail.text = detailTitleS
                }
                imageDetail?.getDataInBackground(block: { (data:Data?, error:Error?) in
                     if error == nil {
                         if let imageData = data {
                             DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
                                 self.imageDetail.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                             }
                          } else {
                               print(error!)
                          }
                      }
                })
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: что-то выводит ? ошибки логи ?

Comment: это должно помочь с ошибками https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46439892/why-i-am-getting-lazy-loading-nsbundle-mobilecoreservices-framework

Comment: а вот с вашим кодом не понятно, выводит ? "image in imageView is nil" , "image data is nil" , "Saved successful" ? Поставьте брейктоинты в классе на разных ивентах и посмотрите что срабатывает , как и когда

Comment: выводит ? "image in imageView is nil" , "image data is nil" , "Saved successful"

Comment: картинку не грузит, в имейдж вью print("image in imageView is nil") а   return  после выбрасывает(останавливает выполнение) из метода, у вас же дальше этот файл должен идти на запись а там будет nil и скорее всего будет fail

Comment: я вообще не особо понимаю зачем вы в методе сначала записываете на сервер а потом читаете с него ? это асинхронные операции, они будут выполнятся параллельно, возможен кейс когда вы еще не записали но уже пытаетесь прочитать и естественно ничего не будет

Comment: что должен сделать метод ?

Comment: ну точнее понятно что он делает но не понятно зачем именно так )

Comment: так зачем тогда кусок кода  в методе detailObject до let query = PFQuery(className: "soccer")