# Как правильно добавить в UITableViewCell вниз в право кнопку?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton

Ребята подскажите как в google почет.Как добавить кнопку, я когда пытаюсь добавить она уходит в верх и соединяется с Cell.Очень буду благодарен добрым, людям.

Comment: а как вы добавляете ?

Comment: как обычно хочу ее поставить внизу справа, а она расползаешься по ширине и слипается с сell вверху.

Comment: ну как минимум можно в сториборде/ксибе нарисовать и выставить размеры, можно и захардкодить это дело и ничего не будет вылезать, потому и спрашиваю как вы делали

Comment: Закардхордить это как?

Comment: button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 20)
button.center = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50) координты для примера

Comment: А понял ...Я этот метод еще осваиваю. Практики мало.Андрей слушайте не поможете с другим вопросом, у меня во ViewController не отображаются данные с сервера?в чем еще может быть проблема.

Comment: код в студию, а так - не приходит ответ с сервера/ответ не в том потоке/ не обновляете юай

Comment: ссылка на вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/723460/parse-com-не-происходить-загрузка-данных